# metrics on the set of all integrable function fails

Tags: real-analysis

Let $R[a,b]$ be the set of all integrable functions and let $f,g \in R[a,b]$ and define

$$ d(f,g) = \int\limits_a^b |f(t)-g(t)| dt $$

IS this a metric on $R[a,b]$? My believe is that it is not, but I can't find a counterexample. My idea is to use some piecewise function and show that $d(f,g) = 0$ may occur even if $ f \neq g$. Is it possible to construct such an example?

Comment: Take $g$ the same as $f$ but $g(a) \neq f(a)$.

Comment: Take functions that differ at exactly one point.

Comment: Does $d(f, g) = 0$ imply $f =g$? For instance, when $g = 0$ so that $d(f, 0) = 0$, then does this imply that $f = 0$ (i.e., if $\int_a^b|f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x=0$, do we have $f = 0$ identically? You may be able to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f, g : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by:

1) $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

$$
g(x) =\left\{
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1, & if & x \neq  \dfrac{1}{2}\\
\dfrac{1}{4}, &  if & x = \dfrac{1}{2} \\
 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Note that $f$ and $g$ differ by only one point, so: $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} g(x) dx$$ Thus: $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx - \int_{0}^{1} g(x) dx = 0 \Leftrightarrow \int_{0}^{1}(f(x) - g(x))dx = 0$$

note that in the given interval $f(x) \geq g(x)$, this is,  $f(x) - g(x) \geq 0$, therefore: $$|f(x) - g(x)| = f(x) - g(x)$$ Then: $$d(f,g) = \int_{0}^{1}|f(x) - g(x)|dx = \int_{0}^{1}(f(x) - g(x))dx = 0$$ But, $f \neq g$.

So, $R[a,b]$ it's not a metric space.

Comment: Perfect answer by the Allan Ramos.